# JavaScript - I create a function which can sum(start,end) and I want it to return "ERROR" when input is String but it doesn't work

Tags: javascript, string, function, boolean

here is what I've tried
`

```
function sumAll(start, end) {
  let average = Math.abs(start + end) / 2;
  let numberOfTerms = Math.abs(end - start) / 1 + 1;
  if (start >= 0 && end >= 0 ) {
    return Math.abs(average * numberOfTerms);
  } else if(typeof start === 'string' || typeof end === 'string'){
    return "ERROR";
  }else{
    return "ERROR";
  }
}
console.log("sumAll(10, '90') =" + sumAll(10, "90")); // I want this to return "ERROR" because "90" is String
console.log("sumAll(10, '90') =" + sumAll(10, "x"));// this works
```

`

but when I change input to "x" it works just fine. I think I miss something.
feel free to tell me anything, I'm a beginner. I'd love to learn new thing.

Comment: `"1" >= 0` is `true`. Do the type check _first_.

Comment: could you elaborate why should I do the type check first? (I've no clue)

Comment: now I know from the comment below, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is a great rule of thumb to do the validation first before anything else. because Javascript is a high level language, string that has only digit(s) in it like `"1"` or `"100"` or `"123"`, Javascript will convert them into number automatically when you do comparison, subtraction, multiplication and division with other number or digit(s) only string. but not addition, because Javascript will concatenate the string instead.

```js
function sumAll(start, end) {
  if(typeof start !== "number" || typeof end !== "number") return "ERROR";
  ...
}
```

Comment: I think I'm not paying attention much at this part when I learned this.
I'm going to have a look at this part again. Thank you
today I learn new thing. Have a nice day!